# Prevent images from downloading with ScrAPI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, screen-scraping

I need to scrape some websites, and would like to avoid downloading images from the pages I am scraping - I only need the text.  I am hoping this will speed up the process. Any ideas on how to manage this?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While scraping you do not download images but the reference `IMG` tag along with the entire `body`. You can always remove the `IMG` tag on the server side before storing into your database/rendering to the view. I would suggest you use nokogiri to parse the content received and remove all occurrences of the `IMG` tag.

This however does not speed up the process. Its just plain old `html` that is scraped. If you want fast fetching and parsing go for `Feedzirra` if you are dealing with feeds or `Typhoeus` for fetching just the html content.

Comment: Ok,  thanks for explaining that.  I will have a look at Typhoeus.